# Failed git replace: replace depth too high for object

Tags: git

I was experimenting with `git replace` and made an error.  Now I can't get back to a sane state.  Any significant git command yields the error `fatal: replace depth too high for object b769532341677b7c34b5adeb85a173daa0ced852`.  `git reset --hard` and `git checkout <another_branch>` just yield this error.

I don't care about the result of the `replace`, I just want to get back to normal.  How might I do that?

Comment: does `git replace -d b769532341677b7c34b5adeb85a173daa0ced852` not work?

Comment: You should be able to simply delete the extra replacement name, as @jthill suggests.

Comment: @jthill that works perfectly!  If you create an answer, I'll mark that as a solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete replacements explicitly,

```
git replace -d b769532341677b7c34b5adeb85a173daa0ced852
```

should do.

Comment: If there are multiple replacements, `git replace -l` will list them all (rather than discovering them one at a time); and `for HID in $(git replace -l) ; do git replace -d $HID ; done` will delete all of them.

Comment: @msleigh AWESOME!